Ubuntu 24.04 Upgrade Corrupted My Drive and Caused Instability on Dell Precision T1700
I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 on my Dell Precision T1700. Unfortunately, the upgrade process corrupted my drive and caused system crashes. After reinstalling, I encountered numerous error logs and instability issues. Running CHKDSK /f/r fixed some issues, but the system remained unstable even after a fresh installation on a raw partition.
System Specifications:
Processor: Intel® Core ™ i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
RAM: 24.0 GB
BIOS Version/Date: Dell Inc. A28, 30/05/2019
Issue Description:
Drive corruption during the upgrade process.
System crashes immediately post-upgrade.
Numerous error logs and persistent instability issues even after running CHKDSK /f/r.
System instability despite performing a fresh installation on a raw partition.
Impact: This malfunction has caused significant frustration and inconvenience, costing a day and a half of work. All saved profiles and settings were lost, adding to the disruption.
Request for Assistance: I am seeking guidance on the following:
Steps to avoid such issues in future upgrades.
Ensuring a stable installation of Ubuntu 24.04 on my system.
Information on any known compatibility issues with Ubuntu 24.04 on Dell Precision T1700 hardware.
Preventive measures to avoid recurrence of these issues.
Conclusion: I would greatly appreciate any assistance or advice on how to resolve these issues and ensure a smooth upgrade process in the future. Thank you for your attention and support.

Please add some of those error messages to your question above.

Sorry, All was deleted. The Ubuntu notification to upgrade completely crashed both drives. I had to use a Microsoft media creation tool just to get my pc up and running again, to access the damage to the system and drives, this step took six hours. I have tried for months to get a stable Ubuntu disto to install without error logs, I have also tried going all the way back to Ubuntu 12.04 and that did not even recognise an ethernet connection.

Unfortunately, there seems not enough information to offer useful advice. Ubuntu installs on most hardware easily and without error. Without details, we cannot explore why your hardware seems unusually balky. Installs with errors are not likely to release-upgrade well. Sorry.

What else do you want to know. I was on my multi-boot desktop. I was using Ubuntu 22. 04.4, I had finally got rid of all the error logs with the help from Copilot Pro, as I am brand new to Ubuntu and Linux. I wanted to leave Windows behind me. I received a notification from Ubuntu to upgrade. I thought "I've only just got this version to work without errors and the Bluetooth was working for the first time. My thoughts were, if Ubuntu do the upgrade and scan my system first which it did, maybe Ubuntu can get 24.04 to work on my desktop. I was excited and clicked upgrade. So 20 character left???
